# how to identify and sum the number of different entries in different categeries?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that can be simplified as follows. I want to calculate, for each state that is in V1, how many different ids appear?

```
state=c("CA","NY","WA")
require(data.table)
comb=CJ(state,rep(2010:2012,2))
comb$id=c(1,3,2,4,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,3,2,5,2,1,1)
comb
    V1   V2 id
 1: CA 2010  1
 2: CA 2010  3
 3: CA 2011  2
 4: CA 2011  4
 5: CA 2012  1
 6: CA 2012  1
 7: NY 2010  2
 8: NY 2010  3
 9: NY 2011  4
10: NY 2011  4
11: NY 2012  5
12: NY 2012  1
13: WA 2010  3
14: WA 2010  2
15: WA 2011  5
16: WA 2011  2
17: WA 2012  1
18: WA 2012  1
```

Eventually, I want to form a table like this:

```
    V1   V2 freq
 1: CA 2010  2
 3: CA 2011  2
 5: CA 2012  1
 7: NY 2010  2
 9: NY 2011  2
11: NY 2012  2
13: WA 2010  2
15: WA 2011  2
17: WA 2012  1
```

That is, for a particular state (in V1), in a particular year (in V2), I want to know how many different ids are there, and form a table like the one above. For example, for state CA in year 2010, there are two ids: 1 and 3. So the freq is 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `NY 2011` be `1`

Comment: `aggregate(id~V1+V2,comb,function(n) length(unique(n)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `uniqueN` using the devel version of `data.table` i.e. [`v1.9.5`](http://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

```
library(data.table) 
comb[, list(freq=uniqueN(id)),.(V1, V2)]
#    V1   V2 freq
#1: CA 2010    2
#2: CA 2011    2
#3: CA 2012    1
#4: NY 2010    2
#5: NY 2011    1
#6: NY 2012    2
#7: WA 2010    2
#8: WA 2011    2
#9: WA 2012    1
```

Comment: I tried -uniqueN- on two computers, but they both do not recognize the function. (I installed data.table)

Comment: @user3602466 Which version do you have ?  I am using the devel version `data.table_1.9.5`.  You can install it from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: @akrun where this comb coming from ? why do I get error by invoking it ? I first use library (data.table) then I use the function you mentioned, I get an error like Error: object 'comb' not found

Comment: @Nemo `comb` is the object defined in the OP's post.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
library (sqldf)
sqldf("select count(distinct id) from comb group by V1")
```